# Solve recurrence T(n)=2T(n-1)+n for n greater than 1 and T(1)=1

Tags: recurrence-relation

**Problem statement**: Solve $T(n)$ for $T(n)=2T(n-1)+n$, $n > 1$, and  $T(1)=1$.

**My attempt**: I tried back substituting but I am unable to find a general pattern:
$$\begin{align*}
T(n) &=2^2 T(n-2)+3n-2 \\
&=2^3 T(n-3)+7n-10 \\
&=2^4 T(n-4)+15n-34 \\
&=\cdots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with (solving recurrences using) generating functions?

Comment: Yes, but what will be T(0) , the initial condition? As that expression right of T(n)  is only valid for n>=2

Comment: You can always "shift" the function $T$ by setting $T_1(n) = T(n + 1)$ and solving the recurrence for $T_1$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 2T(n-1) + n \\
&= 2^2 T(n-2) + (2n + n) - 2 \\
&= 2^3 T(n-3) + (2^2n + 2n + n) - (2^2 \cdot 2 - 2) \\
&= 2^4 T(n-4) + (2^3n + 2^2n + 2n + n) - (2^3 \cdot 3 + 2^2 \cdot 2 + 2^1 \cdot 1) \\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}$$

If you are familiar with the required methods, you can also solve it using generating functions (and, e.g., techniques from [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3135/70382) or chapter 7 of ["Concrete Mathematics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics) by Graham, Knuth, et al.).

Answer (score 2):

A different general method to solve these recurrences is to frame them as a matrix multiplication :

$$
\left( \begin{matrix}T_{n+1}\\ n+1 \\ 1\end{matrix} \right) 
= 
\left( \begin{matrix}2T_{n}+n+1\\ n+1 \\ 1\end{matrix} \right)
= 
\underbrace{\left( \begin{matrix}2&1&1 \\ 0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1\end{matrix} \right)}_M
\left( \begin{matrix}T_{n}\\ n \\ 1\end{matrix} \right)
$$

Now you have:
$$
\left( \begin{matrix}T_{n}\\ n \\ 1\end{matrix} \right)
=
M^n
\left( \begin{matrix}1\\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix} \right)
$$

You can get $M^n$ in $O(log(n))$ time through exponentiation.

Comment: Furthermore, by finding the Jordan form of $M$, you can extract the closed form solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to consider the related sequence $S(n) = T(n)/2^n$, which satisfies the recurrence
$$
S(n) = S(n-1) + \frac{n}{2^n},
$$
whose solution is simply
$$
S(n) = S(1) + \sum_{m=2}^n \frac{m}{2^m}.
$$
The sum can be evaluated in many ways, for example (adding the $m=1$ term)
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m}{2^m} = \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{2^m} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{m=k}^n \frac{1}{2^m} =
\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2^{k-1}} - \frac{1}{2^n} \right) = 2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}.
$$
This shows that
$$
S(n) = 2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}, \quad T(n) = 2^{n+1} - n - 2.
$$
Indeed, one calculates that $T(1) = 2^2-1-2 = 1$, and
$$
T(n) - 2T(n-1) = 2^{n+1} - n - 2 - 2(2^n - n - 1) = n.
$$